# ajax API, can't get the data from API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, api, get

I'm trying to request data from API, I have tried in POSTMAN, and the API works fine, but when I tried it in ajax, there's no data.
my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://food2fork.com/api/search",
            beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            },
            data: { "q": a, "key": "38008dc1ca51f61c514c7e1393d55372" },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                var list = data.recipes;
                alert(list[0].title);
                Builddivs(list);
            }
        });
```

I have also tried

```
$.get('http://food2fork.com/api/search', { q: a,key:"38008dc1ca51f61c514c7e1393d55372" }, function(data) {
            alert(1);
            var list = data.recipes;
            alert(list[0].title);
        });
```

it doesn't work either...
here is the link to the documentation
http://food2fork.com/about/api

the working POSTMAN screenshot is here
[image]
Can anyone fix it?

Comment: Should the type be "POST" ?

Comment: it is get in the documentation..@The One and Only ChemistryBlob

Comment: What result or errors are you getting? Check the JavaScript console or the Network tab in developer tools of your  browser.

Comment: could you also post a screenshot of your working POSTMAN call?

Comment: @Alexandru Marculescu, I have updated the question, thanks!